# styled-component generate custom css class

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a question about the `styled-components` library. I know that this may not be an idiomatic way to do things, but I am curious if there is a styled-component method that can return a CSS class name. I would then be able to pass that class name into components that I render. This way, I can reuse some CSS. Then again, maybe this defeats the purpose of having isolated styled scoped to a single component.

For example, is there a function like `generateCss`?

```
const Button = styled.div`
  background-color: blue;
`

const myCssClassName = styled.generateCss`
    background-color: blue;
`
...
<Button className={myCssClassName} />
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. The whole idea of `styled-components` is to return new components. And if you want to create classes you should have a look at `glamor` or `aphrodite`. And here is [a link](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1180) to a discussion on github.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize an existing styled component, you can use the [`.extend()` API](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles).

For example:

```
const Button = styled.div`
  background-color: red;
`;

const BlueButton = Button.extend`
  background-color: blue;
`;

export default () => (
  <BlueButton />
);
```